# Find duplicates in Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates, conditional-formatting

i have an Excel sheet contain information about 1000 person.

The purpose is a method that allow to select all Rows that contain the same information based on the select columnS

Given the following information in Excel:

```
Code   first-Nam   Last-Nam   Date           Room
01     Jack        Ben        01-01-1995     01
02     Merry       ley        12-02-1994     09
03     jack        Ben        01-01-1995     08
04     Merry       nadia      12-11-1991     02
```

- Based on only the columns contain: First-Nam, Last-Nam, and Date.

The resulted selected "Rows" need to be:

```
Code   first-Nam   Last-Nam   Date           Room
0100   Jack        Ben        01-01-1995     01
1002   jack        Ben        01-01-1995     08
```

The duplication is in general and not based on one name or one date.

Comment: Do you want a **filter** or a **copy elsewhere** method ??

Comment: i want a filter. without changing the original information.

Comment: Just use the `Advanced Filter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using your data as a Table (so that the column references are easily made dynamic) and the advanced filter with formula criteria.  You don't have to use a table, but be sure to use absolute references for the columns if you do not.

We use formula for the criteria.

```
A2: =COUNTIF(Table1[first-Nam],B7)>1
B2: =COUNTIF(Table1[Last-Nam],C7)>1
C2: =COUNTIF(Table1[Date],D7)>1
```

And here are some screen shots, before and after

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @SimoOs As you can see from the screenshots, it works as you seemed to desire given your data and the method I outlined.  If it is not working on your real data, then there is either something different about your actual data, or you have not implemented the solution as I described.  I would suggest you check Help for the Advanced Filter to try to figure out your error.  The limited amount of information provided in your comment is not sufficient to allow more troubleshooting at this end.

Comment: Thank you soo much

Comment: @SimoOs If this solution is what you need, I would appreciate it if you could mark it as the answer.  If not, let's troubleshoot further.

Comment: Im trying ti figure out the problem that i got. i will mark it as an answer as soon as possible. and i am soooooo thankful for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Identify the duplicates with a quick [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) rule. Use the applied backfill color as the criteria in a [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) operation.

```
Sub filterDupes()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 3).Offset(1, 1)
                .FormatConditions.Delete
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
                    "=AND(COUNTIFS($B:$B, $B2,$C:$C, $C2,$D:$D, $D2)-1)"
                .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
            End With
            With .Columns(2)
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=vbRed, _
                            Operator:=xlFilterCellColor, _
                            VisibleDropDown:=False  '<~~ turns off showing the dropdown arrow
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Using the color from a CR rule is analogous to adding a 'helper' column that identifies the duplicates without altering the worksheet structure.

[image: color_remove_duplicates_before]
                 <sup>[Sample data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Find%20duplicates%20in%20Excel_CFR_Filter_by_Color.xlsb) before filterDupes()</sup>

[image: color_remove_duplicates_during]
                 <sup>[Sample data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Find%20duplicates%20in%20Excel_CFR_Filter_by_Color.xlsb) with Conditional Formatting rule applied</sup>

[image: color_remove_duplicates_after]
                 <sup>[Sample data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Find%20duplicates%20in%20Excel_CFR_Filter_by_Color.xlsb) after filterDupes()</sup>